# How to get system localized string such as "Folder","OK", "Yes",tec

Tags: macos

which location does the system put resources, for example, i can get NSImage by NSImageFolder to get system image for a folder, but how can i do that to get system localized string "Folder" programmatically?

Comment: Many of them are in `Localizable.strings` of the Finder (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`)

Comment: The .strings files are encrypted

Comment: No, at least `Localizable.strings` is not. Try this code in Swift `let finderBundle = NSBundle(path:"/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app")!
    print(NSLocalizedString("AL11", tableName: nil, bundle: finderBundle, value: "", comment: ""))`. That's supposed to print *Secure Empty Trash* on an english system.